# Linux: keyboard mapping accents like OS X

Tags: linux, keyboard

Comming from OS X, I would like to change my keyboard mapping so that:

- Map <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to `dead_acute`  (for instance <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> should produce `á`)
- Map <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to `dead_circumflex` (for instance <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> should produce `ô`)
- Map <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to `ccedilla`

If possible I would like also to map <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to `/`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not write what flavor of Linux you are using, my answer may be not suiting. If it is Debian derived (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint), you could use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

which would guide you through all the possible sections, such as language, keyboard variants (which is what you are asking about), and even special keyboard bindings. Keep in mind that this changes the layout system-wide (not only for your user).

On the other hand, most desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, etc.) provide graphical interfaces for user-based settings. On KDE4, you can find this e.g. in Settings->Systemsettings, selecting "input devices" in the hardware section.

You can find more answers on this at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151177/keyboard-layout-wont-change/151186).

Comment: I'm using Arch. Tried editing /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us file, and I'm able to make the changes BUT it just works with AltGr (not with Alt) --- to make this changes, I just had to modify the third column associated with the E, O and C keys. But I can't make it work with ALT key

Comment: As you wrote you want it like on Mac, I just remembered there is a XkbVariant "mac", so I assumed that should do it all-in-one? However, if you are not fixed on the Alt key: take a look at the "compose key" stuff there. I configured my right "Windows key" as such. Now, when I e.g. press RWin+/, then o I get the norsk ø, RWin+" then e gives me ë, and so on. This way you can visualize your desired results, and then type intuitively. May be that combination is solving your issue?

Comment: Btw: You might want to take a look into the topic [Remapping keys on keyboard in Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/284089/remapping-keys-on-keyboard-in-linux?rq=1) as well.

Comment: OK us mac is exactly what i want, but with ralt instead of lalt. Tried to edit compose to include a compose(lalt) but it didnt work. I cant use Windows Key since I use it as the Mod key for awesome wm

Comment: Got it.. Just changed level3(ralt_switch) to level3(lalt_switch) on mac session of /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us.    THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I think this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446778/left-alt-key-should-work-as-right-alt-key-alt-gr) is useful, since it has a better way to accomplish this without editing the xkb map file.

The shell command should be:

`setxkbmap us mac lv3:lalt_switch lv3:ralt_alt`